# guard rspec sublime text 2 invalid option command shift R

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sublimetext2, guard

I'm using `rails 3.2` with `rspec 3.0.0` and `guard-rspec (4.3.1) guard (~> 2.1)`

When I use `shift + command + R` I get `invalid option: -l65`

I usually use this to run a test within a describe block. `shift + command + T` works to run all the tests on a page. Does anyone know why this is showing me an invalid option? Thanks

here is my spec_helper.rb

```
 # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
    require 'rspec/rails'
    require 'rspec/autorun'
    require 'capybara/rspec'
    require 'capybara/rails'
    require 'shoulda/matchers'

    # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
    # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
    Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

    # Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
    # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
    #ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

    RSpec.configure do |config|
      # ## Mock Framework
      #
      # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
      #
      # config.mock_with :mocha
      # config.mock_with :flexmock
      # config.mock_with :rr

      # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories 
      config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

      #config geocoder for test
      #Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)

      # Use capybara DSL
      config.include Capybara::DSL

      #include manually made helpers
      config.include AuthenticationHelper


      # Use URL helper
      config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

      # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
      # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

      # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
      # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
      # instead of true.
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

      # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
      # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
      # rspec-rails.
      config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

      # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
      # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
      # the seed, which is printed after each run.
      #     --seed 1234
      config.order = "random"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just deleted the RubyTest package and recloned it with `git clone https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests.git RubyTest`

Comment: sorry I honestly can't remember